# Unique and Aggregate Functions in R

Tags: r, unique, aggregate

For example I have 2 vectors

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,3,3,  3,3,3,4,4,  5,5,5,5,5 )
y <- c(2,2,1,3,2, 1,4,2,2,NA, 3,3,3,4,NA, 1,4,4,2,NA)
```

I have a question: how can I calculate the number of 1s,2s,3s,4s in vector Y for each value  (from 1 to 5) of vector X? Tried to do that with function `unique()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be done with the following one-liner:

```
table(y, x)
##   1 2 3 4 5
## 1 1 1 0 1 1
## 2 3 1 2 0 1
## 3 1 0 3 0 1
## 4 0 1 0 1 2
```

Comment: And how can I put "." instead of 0 in results?

Comment: Maybe: `result <- as.character(table(y, x)); result[result == 0] <- "."`

Comment: And one more question: if I have data.frame with NA, how can I change NA to "."

Comment: Just figured out that it can be done with:               replace(data, is.na(data), ".")

Comment: You have to have guts in order to post that as an answer instead of a comment :)

Comment: @gagolews Hello. Could you say me how to calculate the number of values in vector y for each number (from 1 to 5 ) in vector x. SO, the output should be in format: for x=1, number is 5; for x=2 the number is 4; for x=3 the number is 4; for x=4 the number is 4; for x=5 the number is 4. Thank you!

Comment: Could anybody explain how to find the number of values in Y (don`t count NA) for each X? Fro example, for x=1, number is 5; for x=2 the number is 3; for x=3 the number is 4; for x=4 the number is 1; for x=5 the number is 4